# Calculate the average distance between two data sets of X and Y (in JS)

Tags: javascript, math, graph, chart.js, distance

I have two databases that I've read from an Excel file, and I converted it to JSON. (my project is in JavaScript)

The first database is a planed track that the pilot should follow, and the second database is the actual track.

I need to calculate the average distance between the tracks.
The problem is that the tracks don't have the same amount of points on them and so I don't know what distance should I calculate.

I printed the databases with chart.js and they are looking like this:
[image]

Comment: Could you add some example input data to the question? Do you have a distance or `xy` of where each point is located?

Answer (score -2):

You could use `map()` to calculat the differences, `reduce()` to get the total and then divide by the length.

```js
const distancesA = [17, 54, 87, 101, 120];
const distancesB = [12, 57, 82, 100, 125];

const averageDistance = distancesA.map((d, i) => d - distancesB[i]).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / distancesA.length;

console.log(averageDistance)
```

Comment: This does only work if A and B have the same amount of entries, as OP stated in his question in his case both datasets have a different amount of entries